# How to use OpenCV to capture live video feed from multiple cameras?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, video-capture

I am using Opencv 3 and python 3.6 for my project work. I want to set up multiple cameras at a time to see video feed from all of them at once. I want to do facial recognition using it. But there is no good way to do this. Here is one link which I followed but nothing happens: [Reading from two cameras in OpenCV at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664399/reading-from-two-cameras-in-opencv-at-once)

I have tried this blog post as well but it only can capture one image at a time from video and cannot show the live video. 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/

Previously people have done this with C++ but with python it seems difficult to me.

Comment: Are you able to read from each camera, one at a time?

Comment: Yes I am. reading from single camera is not issue

Comment: You seem to be following correct sample code on how to achieve this. If you paste your code here, perhaps we can help debug it.

Comment: are you sure about it? Well i am not changing a bit in a code. I am just copying it to see how it works or not

Comment: Paste your code here and perhaps we can help debug if you're still stuck on the problem

Answer (score 1):

the below code works and i've tested it, so if u're using two cameras 1 a webcam  and another is a usb cam then, (adjust videocapture numbers if both are usb cam)

```
import cv2


cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while 1:

  ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
  ret2, img2 = cap2.read()

  if ret1 and ret2:

      cv2.imshow('img1',img1)
      cv2.imshow('img2',img2)

      k = cv2.waitKey(100) 
      if k == 27: #press Esc to exit
         break

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what If we have more than 10 webcams. any solution using looping ?? or any predefined method or library ??

Comment: I dont know how you are gonna add 10 webcams in one pc
 anyways just add cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(3) and keep adding ..although i should tell you that  the program would run very slowly the more you webcams you add

Answer (score 0):

my experience with R_Pi & 2 cams showed the limitation was the GPU on the R_Pi.
I used setup to allocate more GPU memory to 512Mb.
It would slow down with more than 10 fps with 2 cams.
Also, the USB ports restricted the video stream.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put each camera on it's own usb controller. I did this using a 4 channel PCIe card. The card must have a separate controller for each port. I'm just finishing a project where I snap images from 4 ELP usb cameras, combine the images into one, and write it to disk. I spent days trying to make it work. I found examples for two cameras that worked with my laptop camera and an external camera but not two external cameras. The internal camera is on a different usb controller than the external ports...