Two USB webcams don't work with rapsberry pi
This is my first time using Stack overflow, and in general I am new to programming, engineering, Raspberry Pi, etc...
For the purposes of producing some form of steroscopic vision I am using two arducam USB 2.0 vl/ir webcams and interfacing them with OpenCV. To start off simple, I simply tried to produce and display video feeds from both webcams in a python script. The code is as follows:
import cv2

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

while True:
    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()

    cv2.imshow('Video Feed 1', frame1)
    cv2.imshow('Video Feed 2', frame2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

*Please note that my webcams come up in the dev directory as two devices each, (ex. cam1 comes up as /dev/video0 and /dev/video1) so to access each of them I have to call dev0 and dev2.
When running this code I get the error "gstreamer: could not query video position". This error I have read is harmless, but I have mentioned it anyways. When running this code with each webcam individually it works perfectly. As soon as I even initialize a second webcam it gives me the gstreamer error and displays nothing. The shell does not terminate the program, however, it keeps going like its still trying to work, but it never displays anything.
I thought it may have been a power problem, so I bought a USB 2.0 powered hub. Even after that it didn't work. Bandwidth may be a problem, but even when I reduce the resolution of each webcam to 320x240 the program still doesn't work. To isolate the problem further, I tried capturing video from the webcams using the terminal to see if that worked. If it did, it would have shown that the problem was pythons fault. However, after using ffplay attempt to capture video from both cameras at the same time in the terminal, it only captured video from one at a time, showing that the data flow from the other was zero. This may confirm the bandwidth problem, or it may be that ffplay doesn't support using two webcams at the same time. Either way, I am not sure what the problem is.
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

i dont have 2 cams to test with, but there appear to be two approaches. Multithreading and Sequential. You appear to have used the Sequential approach correctly so an answer would be interesting.  However, have you tried the Multithreading ?

also, this might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664399/capturing-video-from-two-cameras-in-opencv-at-once

Can you try a different usb camera as the second device? Maybe the driver isnt working with two "identical" cameras?

Can you try these things to access both cams at the same time? https://docs.arducam.com/UVC-Camera/Quick-Start-for-Different-Systems/Linux/

Index should be 1 cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) not 2

I have tried to use a different USB webcam and the same thing happened. I will try multi-threading using the library CamGear API made by abhiTronix.

I tried multi threading and the shell gave an error saying that multi-threading wasn't available for the device. I was using the VidGear library. I also tried to size down the resolution of the webcams to 120 by 160 and only display two images, and the result it gave was one image that showed an image captured from a camera, and one image that was just black, supposedly from the second camera, showing that that camera did not return anything.
